# Load mountpoint in a Custom page using ECL Content Library

Tags: core-service, ecl, custom-page, web8

I am developing a custom page to upload components in CMS using Core service. Image fields in component will refer media manager images. I have ecl uris for images so i need to create stub for them and then use the tcmid of stubs in creating component.
Stubs can be created using ECL Content Library but i could not find any reference for using ECL Content Library in Custom page.

Answer (score 4):

As Lars explained in [this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/13079/1678),  you can create MM components using EclService. You can access it via mountpoint in Core Service.

Comment: Hi @Marco Milic I am getting below error while trying to use method     'public IDictionary<string, string> CreateOrGetStubUris(IEnumerable<string> eclItemUris) '                     Error Occured while creating Xml-msgAccessDeniedForImpersonationUser

Comment: The user you're running as (by default, NETWORK SERVICE) is not allowed to access Tridion - you need to impersonate.

Comment: @NunoLinhares I tried to impersonate client with "domainname\\validuser"  but on impersonate step it gives me below exception:

Comment: The user you're trying to impersonate must exist in Tridion. Also afterwards, make sure that he has the appropriate rights/permissions to execute the desired action or else you'll get another exception.

Comment: I am using the User who has admin rights in CMS. It looks like the way i am using Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.dll is not correct.

Comment: Thanks @Marko it worked i was trying to impersonate user that's why it was not working and when i tried with network credentials on client then it worked.

Comment: If it helped, please mark answer as accepted. :D